# How to clone a TPanel in Delphi FMX application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am building a application using FMX. This app will run on Windows, Mac OSX, and Linux.

I have a need to clone a `TPanel` which is contained in another `TPanel`.

Clone function provided in FMX is throwing an error:

> Class TForm1 not found.

How to clone a `TPanel` in an FMX app?

Here is the code I am using:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurrentControl, ClonedControl: TFMXObject;
  CtlrNameCnt: String;
begin
  CtlrNameCnt := IntToStr(Panel1.ControlsCount);

  CurrentControl := Panel1;

  ClonedControl := Clone(CurrentControl); //<- this gives error
  ClonedControl.name := CurrentControl.name + '_' + CtlrNameCnt;
  ClonedControl.Parent := Panel1;
end;
```

Comment: If it were VCL I'd try `RegisterClass(TForm1)`.

Comment: Would be helpful to back up and post your original problem/error and not just something from a solution you are attempting. Guessing your original error was something like `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(30): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TPanel' and 'TFmxObject'` and you then added the declaration of CurrentControl as TFMXObject in an effort to get around that error.

Comment: In your code you are actually cloning TForm1 and not a panel. It is very unclear what should be cloned and what the parent of the clone is supposed to be.

Comment: `Clone` is actually `Self.Clone` and the argument that you pass becomes the owner of the cloned object. Not what you want.

Comment: @Brain, There is not compile time error. This error occurs during run time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks for pointing out my simple mistake. This did the trick. I finally manage to build a working solution!

Answer (score 1):

There were two major mistakes that I was making in my code.

Here is the code that works without any problem:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurrentControl, ClonedControl: TFMXObject;
  CtlrNameCnt: String;
begin
  CtlrNameCnt := IntToStr(Panel1.ControlsCount);

  CurrentControl := Panel1;

  ClonedControl := Panel2.Clone(CurrentControl); //<- this Works now!
  ClonedControl.name := CurrentControl.name + '_' + CtlrNameCnt;
  ClonedControl.Parent := Panel1;
end;
```

TIA

Yogi Yang